# android progress bar background opacity

Tags: android, opacity, android-progressbar

I've been using Android ProgressBar quite a lot.
The only thing here is for a specific app, i need the ProgressBar not to have a translucent background. I mean you can still see the View behind it as the progressbar is semi-transparent.

Actually I need a full background opacity (black, white, doesn't matter). As long as the panel behind could be hidden using the progress bar.
I cannot just use the Panel behind itself and set a background as it's a Web Panel (where JS stuff is happening).

Thanks for your replies

regards

Comment: you want to use progress bar as your image right ????

Comment: Nope, actually using a progress bar normally but i don't want the view behind to be seen (as you can see the progress bar is displayed on top of the current view and you can't still see a glimpse of it behind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.
Actually i created my own Custom Progress Bar.
An example can be found here :
[Create you Custom Progress Dialog](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/how-to-make-custom-indeterminate-progressbar-in-android-or-how-to-change-progressbar-style-or-color)

Then i just blured the background of the dialog using this approach :
[Blur Dialog](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-blurring-and-dimming-background-windows-from-dialogs/)

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) progressDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
tv.setTextColor(Portlet.MessageFontColor);

View v = (View) tv.getParent();
((ScrollView) v).setBackgroundColor(Portlet.messageBackColor);

v = (View) v.getParent();
v.setBackgroundColor(Portlet.messageBackColor);

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
ll.setBackgroundColor(Portlet.messageBackColor);
```